# words choice and use

Tags: passive-voice

Which sentence is correct:

> Raju is being developed day to day.
>   Raju is developing day to day.

And can I say that

> Raju has been developed by himself?

Please tell me these three examples.

Comment: Is **Raju** a person? What is the intended meaning of the sentence?

Comment: *Raju* is a person's name. Maybe, Sandesh (An Indian) wants to say that Raju is a *'self-made'* person.

Answer (score 0):

The third sentence doesn't make much sense and it's wordy so don't use it.

It largely depends on the context of the sentence but if Raju is a thing (software, robot, etc.) then the first sentence means that someone is developing it (someone is doing the work), improving it and so on.

The second sentence conveys that Raju is developing by himself/itself. This might not be  the case, but as the sentence stands on its own that's what it conveys. 
It could mean that someone is developing Raju but on its own it's ambiguous.